# Is there a way to isolate the months in javascript daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I'm implementing a daterangepicker into my application and am wondering how to confine each month to ONLY that month.  For example:

I would like this (see the left hand calendar):

[image]

But the default is like this

[image]

I've reviewed the [DateRangePicker Documentation](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) and cannot see a configuration that will do this for me.

My DateRangePicker initilization:

```
$("#reportrange").daterangepicker
      ranges:
         "Last Week": [moment().subtract("days", moment().day() + 1).subtract("days", 6), moment().subtract("days", moment().day() + 1)]
         "Week to Date": [moment().subtract("days", moment().day()), moment()]
         "Last Month": [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      startDate: moment().subtract("days", moment().day() + 1).subtract("days", 6)
      endDate: moment().subtract("days", moment().day() + 1),
      alwaysShowCalendars: true
   , (start, end, label) ->
         $("#reportrange span").html start.format("MMMM D, YYYY") + " - " + end.format("MMMM D, YYYY")
         $("[name*='_start_date']").val(start.format("ddd, D MMM YYYY"))
         $("[name*='_end_date']").val(end.format("ddd, D MMM YYYY")).trigger 'change'
```

My DateRangePicker Frontend with ruby templating

```
.grid-24.box
   .grid-12
      %h3 Select Date Range
      #reportrange
         %i.glyph-calendar.icon-large
         %span= "#{(DateTime.now - (DateTime.now.wday + 1) - 6).strftime("%B %d, %Y")} - #{(DateTime.now - (DateTime.now.wday + 1)).strftime("%B %d, %Y")} "
         %b.caret
      =hidden_field_tag "charge_start_date", DateTime.now.prev_month.strftime("%a,  %d %b %Y")
      =hidden_field_tag "charge_end_date", DateTime.now.strftime("%a,  %d %b %Y")
.grid-24#display-charges
   =render :partial => "user_charge_data_display", :locals => {users: @users, start_range: (DateTime.now - 30), end_range: DateTime.now}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the documentation and couldn't find the way to do it programmatically, using developers' provided configuration.
However, in such situation, you can always go with CSS work-around, by applying `visibility: hidden;` to the CSS class of the items that are beyond the current month date.
Here's what I did:

```
.daterangepicker td.off, .daterangepicker td.off.in-range, .daterangepicker td.off.start-date, .daterangepicker td.off.end-date {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: I actually came across this solution myself shortly after asking.  The problem here is that with display: none, the values are pushed back and the number days of the week are not corresponding to the weekdays.  I went with visibility: hidden; and it works like a charm.  If you could update your answer to include that, I will accept it.

Comment: very nice! Updated to "visibility: hidden;" as suggested